# getImageData() on Chrome seems to change the image data

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-canvas, cryptojs

When I generate a Canvas element and try to retrieve one pixel of image - it seems to somehow change the image underneath. This only happens on Chrome and not on Safari. Can someone point out why this might be happening?

```
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.height = 512;
            canvas.width = 512;
            var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.style.display = 'inline';
            canvasContext.textBaseline = 'alphabetic';
            canvasContext.font = '12pt Arial';
            canvasContext.fillText("some text", 2, 25);
            canvasDataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            var raw_hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(canvasDataURL);
            var hash = raw_hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
            console.log('chash: ' + hash);
            canvasPixelData2 = canvasContext.getImageData(50, 50, 1, 1);
            canvasDataURL2 = canvas.toDataURL();
            var raw_hash2 = CryptoJS.SHA256(canvasDataURL2);
            var hash2 = raw_hash2.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
            console.log('chash2: ' + hash2);
```

Sample output:

[image]

**Update**: I have verified that a total of 11 pixels have changed in my 512 by 512 sized image. The changes have all been by only one pixel value (reduced by 1). But, I still don't understand why this is happening or how this can be prevented.

**Update 2**: To better demonstrate the issue, I built a test website here: https://fatherofthenation.xyz/cfp/sample.htm
Below is the output I get on Chrome from the above website.

[image]

Comment: Neither the image nor the `data` URIs are changed. The issue is either in your use of CryptoJS, or there’s something else going on that we don’t see.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I verified that this is not the case - this doesn't seem to have anything to do with CryptoJS. The data URLs have in fact changed; the same behavior is being exhibited on Brave as well (which is a Chrome-based browser).

Comment: Still cannot reproduce this. The data URI doesn’t change in any browser I test this in (Firefox 80, Chrom{e, ium} 83.0.4103.116, Epiphany 3.36.3): `const context = Object.assign(Object.assign(document.createElement("canvas"), { width: 512, height: 512 }).getContext("2d"), { textBaseline: "alphabetic", font: "12pt Arial" }); context.canvas.style.display = "inline"; context.fillText("some text", 2, 25); const uri1 = context.canvas.toDataURL(); console.log(uri1); const pxData = context.getImageData(50, 50, 1, 1); const uri2 = canvas.toDataURL(); console.log(uri2); console.log(uri1 === uri2);`.

Comment: Thanks for trying; I built a sample website for you here:
https://fatherofthenation.xyz/cfp/sample.htm
I update my question with the output I get from this page.

Comment: Okay, now I see different hashes for Chrome and Chromium.